# Firebase Notification does NOT show up when app is open

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my testing, when send out Firebase Notification to Android, the notification does NOT show up when the user has the app open on the screen. Is this a default behavior?

What should I do if I want the user to always receive notification no matter they have the app open or not?

Comment: can you add your notification (Firebase Messaging) class code?

Comment: I don't have any

Comment: that's why...you need to add ```Firebase Messaging``` class in your project here is the reference https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Answer (score 2):

For notification messages the default behavior is indeed that:

- the OS displays them when the app is not active.
- they're delivered to your application code when the app is active.

Also see:

- The Firebase documentation on [message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).
- [Flutter: Push notifications even if the app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53572110/flutter-push-notifications-even-if-the-app-is-closed), mostly since it shows how to show your own notifications.

Comment: So when the app is not running in the background, the user won't get the notification?

Comment: That'd be the first case/bullet point: if the app is inactive, the system handles display of notifications.

Comment: So when the app is running on the screen, is there a way we can force the notification to show up under the Android notification tray?

Comment: Check that second link under "Also see" in my asnwer, which contains a link to a library that does precisely that as far as I can see.