# Firebase Push Notifications not working on Android 8 and above when app is closed

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Am working with Flutter and I have been looking for a fix for this for a while. At first I thought the notifications are not been received when the app is closed, but it worked on my Android 5 device.
I have added this in my Android Manifest file already

```
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

On the Android 8 and 9 devices i have with me, when I send any push notification from Firebase, i receive the notifications only when the app is running or if i minimize the app. But when the app is completely closed, i don't get the notification at all. Please a fix for this will be highly appreciated as it is the last feature i intend including before release.

My intention is actually sending notifications to all users. I have tried using Flutter Local Notification package too but i receive it on only one device.

Comment: I had faced the similar issue, and i found solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59836752/5830240)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Push notifications even if the app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53572110/flutter-push-notifications-even-if-the-app-is-closed)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but It doesn't

Comment: i have done the same, and it worked for me.