# I want to make Birthday reminder notification using flutter

Tags: flutter

I am making an application using flutter so every teacher has some students in their class so they see their students only in the first screen , I want to send to the teacher notification before each student birthday by 2 days , also i want to send a notification at the beginning of each month (day 1) with all of the birthdays of the students at this month ..

ex: Mark birthday is on 5/9 , Thomas is on 19/9 so i want to send the teacher a notification at day 1 of the month that there is 2 birthdays on this month for Mark and Thomas .

I've searched alot really and i can't do anything .

Comment: I think this question is answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53572110/flutter-push-notifications-even-if-the-app-is-closed).

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `Firebase Messaging` or `One Signal` and need to send notification from the server. You can generate FCM token and then send it to specific devices. Using `Pubsub` in `Firebase Functions` you can check daily notification and check if any birthday is coming after 2 days of the following day. If there is Birthday then it will send the notification to the user using the FCM token registered. Here are some resources:

- [Flutter Firebase Notification using Firebase Functions](https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-push-notifications-fcm-guide/)
- [Schedule Function using Pubsub and Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions)