# How to keep a web socket alive even when app closed?

Tags: flutter, websocket

I'm learning flutter, and I'm trying to make an app interacting with a Rust server.

I've done a bit of things already, all the basics of http requests, and simple menus and displays.

Now I would like to take it a bit further, and have the server send notifications / messages to the app even when it's closed. So idealy, I would like to have a web socket connection between the app and the server.

I've looked up some things, especially this already :

[flutter : push notifications when app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53572110/flutter-push-notifications-even-if-the-app-is-closed)

[Executing dart in the background](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124)

But I can't wrap my head around it all.

How would one keep code running in the background ?
Any explanations on how it all work would also be great !